# drop down is not hidden when I click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script. The script works when i click but it is not hidden when i click outside.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //Translate();  //caling Language Translater function
   $("#translate_image").attr('href', base_url)

   $("#select_lang").click(function() {
      $("#lang_visible").attr('style', 'visibility: visible');
   })
})
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<li>
    <div class="clsCurrent_Lan ">
        <a class="clsHead_Link_Bg" href="#" id="select_lang">
            <span>Select Language</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <ul id="lang_visible" >
        <?php foreach($language_drops as $lang){?>
            <li>
              <a href="<?php echo admin_url('home/ch_language/' . 
                 $lang->language_code)?>"
                 id="<?php echo $lang->language_code?>">
                 <?php echo ucfirst($lang->language_name);?></a>
            </li>
        <?php }?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Please edit your post. You need an empty line before code.

Comment: can u tell me why this is not working

Comment: what should be hidden? `#lang_visible`? What are you clicking on "outside" that you expect to hide the element?

Comment: i want to hide the dropdown when it is in inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).parents('#select_lang').length === 0) {
    $("#lang_visible").attr('style', 'visibility: hidden');
  }
});
```

Try that. Add it within your document ready call. Basically clicking anywhere besides in the #select_lang selector will cause the visibility of #lang_visible to be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going about this the wrong way, sort of like reinventing the wheel.  So the behavior you want is to have a control where the user can select a language from a number of different languages?  Rather than trying to roll your own, why not just use the "Select" element?  You can use php to set up the "Select" initially, and then use javascript/jQuery to respond to state changes.

Answer (score 0):

So, something like this then?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Translate(); //calling Language Translater function
    $("#translate_image").attr('href',base_url);
    $("#select_lang").click(function () {
        $("#lang_visible").attr('style','visibility: visible').click(function (e) {
            $(this).hide(); //hides the #lang_visible element
            //$(this).parent().hide(); //to hide the <li> containing the #lang_visible element
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you post some html markup? This may help us to identify the problem.

Comment: Ok, update code for original answer to hide the dropdown on its change event. Let us know if that works for you.

Comment: I realized you are using `li` and `a` elements for your "dropdown" now (instead of a `select` and `option`). Modified answer, let us know if that works for you.

Comment: yes i used li and a element.now i change the script.now it works fine.